# Qt is not detecting android kits automaticallly

Tags: android, qt, sdk, android-ndk

I am an absolute beginner. I want to install Qt for android development.

I followed the instructions for installing Qt as specified on Qt's website. I installed android manager and set up SDK, NDK, ant and JDK. After this I specified there locations in Qt but Qt is not detecting any kits at all. Why? Is there something that i am missing?

It might help to know that I an running Qt on ubuntu 16.04.3 and my Qt's version is Qt Creator (community) open source free

If I manually add a kit what should I do about sysroot and other empty fields.

What do i do about the empty fields

[image]

Comment: Well just create the kit manually, add in the compiler and qt version if necessary.

Comment: What do i do about the other empty fields

Comment: Did you actually install the android stuff from the Qt Maintenance Tool? Also, you need to setup sdk/ndk in "devices"

Comment: Yes, I have set up sdk and ndk in devices. There is a message below the ndk field which says that 6 non at versions found and to correct them I need to go to build and run > qt versions but i don’t find any qt versions in there.

Comment: Also there is no seperate android button on the left(as you can see in the pic). I think there should be one.

Answer (score 1):

I have the similar problem. Problem was with NDK version. 
The newest NDK version doesn't contains executable gcc compilers (it use clang compiler). I must use NDK version 15.

Answer (score 0):

I had to configure manually as well  for embedded linux.. To configure manually, in case you did all the configuration to  a new qt, i just gotta select your compiler and change the qt version to the one you configured for the cross compiler. All the other option, let by default. Make sure your cross compiler command is set in your PATH.

This qt version is the path to your qmake.